# Puppetserver not coming up after fresh installation

Tags: puppet, rhel6

`Pupppetserver` service is not coming up after fresh installation. It is showing the following error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.Files, compiling:(puppetlabs/puppetserver/certificate_authority.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
......
......
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.Files
```

The system has 2G of memory. I changed the memory settings to 1G from 2G , but the service is still not coming up.

```
  JAVA_ARGS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

  $ cat /etc/redhat-release
  CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

  $ rpm -q puppetserver
   puppetserver-2.7.2-1.el6.noarch
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Which version of Java? Perhaps it's older (e.g. 1.6 rather than 1.7).

Comment: Yeah.....  $ rpm -qf /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java
               jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64

Comment: The puppetserver package appears to depend on java-1.8, so try checking `alternatives` (i.e. /usr/bin/java) is using the 1.8 installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the puppetmaster using Java 6, and it needs a more recent version. Install a newer version of java ( `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless` ) and try again.

Comment: (java.nio.file.Files was new in java 7)